# Initiating action on Save of sheet

Tags: smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have a C# console application (NOT a web application) using the Smartsheet API that can import / export data from / to another application.  What I'd like to do is initiate this app to function on the Save of the Smartsheet worksheet.  I've read about Webhooks, but the documentation, at least on the C# level, is woeful.  I don't regularly (if at all) work in the http POST / GET / Rest and JSON code world, so I don't really understand the examples that are given.  If there are C# examples, I would sincerely appreciate any direction that can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using webhooks to be alerted of changes you could regularly poll the sheet and ask for the version number and store that value.

`// Get sheet version.
smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheetVersion(sheetId);`

Then compare it to the previous version number you got and if the latest version number is higher you know that changes have been made. Then you can initiate your process.

More info on version numbers is in the docs [here](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#get-sheet-version)

Comment: So - the webhooks aren't a viable option?

Comment: Webhooks are a great way to be alerted of changes made to a sheet and can be more effective than regularly polling. But, without having knowledge of REST processes and HTTP methods it may prove difficult to implement them. The Smartsheet documentation is written from the perspective that someone already has prior knowledge of these topics. If you are looking to implement Webhooks in your app I suggest reading up on these topics to learn more about REST and making HTTP requests in C#.

Comment: I can easily learn the http request syntax for REST requests in C# - but how would that be used to implement webhooks in C#?  Can you provide any examples?

Comment: I don't have any specific examples for using webhooks in C#. If you can work out how to send and receive HTTP requests in C# you can use that as a basis for sending the necessary requests to create webhooks and for receiving the callbacks as events occur in the sheet(http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#intro-to-webhooks).

Comment: Will do.  Thanks, Dave.